# NodeJs video streaming issue on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, video-streaming

I have spent my whole day on this. Video streaming is working smoothly on localhost but having issue on production server. I have tried both readstream.pipe() and "stream" pipline to send response. I am using express.

Here is the function responsible to serve video file chunk by chunk:

```
function getStream(videoPath,req,res){
    const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size; //file property (sync)

    var range = req.headers.range;
    if (!range) {
      range = 'bytes=0-';
      console.log('wrong start')
    }

    // Parse Range
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000; // 1MB
    const start = parseInt(range.replace(/\D/g, ""),10);
    console.log('start is: ',start);
    const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);
    console.log('end is: ',end);
    console.log(`Chunk_size: ${CHUNK_SIZE}`)
    // Create headers
    const contentLength = (end-start) + 1;
    console.log(`contentLength: ${contentLength}`)
    const headers = {
      "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": contentLength,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };
    // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
    res.writeHead(206, headers);
    // create video read stream for this particular chunk
    const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
    // videoStream.pipe(res);
    pipeline(videoStream , res, (err) => {
      err && console.error(err);
    });
}
```

**Issue:** *The requested video file is not loading inside the HTML5 video player. The server is not throwing any error/error_code. All console logs are clean and the same as development/localhost. I tried to access the video URL in the browser, The IDM says that the file is corrupted and contains unmatched chunks (obviously file is ok).*

Comment: What is the issue you are trying resolve?

Comment: @Matt this same code works well on localhost, but not on VPS. I don't have any idea..maybe something is wrong with the reverse proxy config .. Is Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Describe what doesn't "work well" on the VPS. Any errors? What does a request look like? How much data are you streaming? etc. It will be hard for people to help without more context of the problem.